# webpage http URL issue

Tags: php, http, header, request

When i try to open my page with normal request something.com my page's few animation is not working properly but if i do the same by typing full address i.e 
http://something.com everything is normal. I tried using php to fix this issue.

```
<?php
    header("Location: http://www.something.com/home.html");
?>
```

However, it's not working.

Comment: I think , it is path problem. you use Inspector element in browser and check if there any errors.

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably the case because you hard coded your base path into the path of the assets you are loading for these animations.

Wrong:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type"text/javascript" src="http://www.something.com/my-asset.js"/>
</head>
```

Right:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type"text/javascript" src="/my-asset.js"/>
</head>
```

If you want full, absolute paths you can also dynamically set a basePath variable and use this in front of the asset path but it's not necessary in many cases.